# Oracle wallet for unmanaged driver

Tags: oracle

Is there any connection string that is different when connecting to Oracle DB through oracle wallet ? Does oracle wallet work with unmanaged driver ?

Comment: connection string specifically for unmanaged driver

Comment: I think your can just write : User Id=/ if you use ODP

Comment: Yes that's right. There is no difference in the connection string, but it is required to set the environment variable tns_admin to the oracle wallet path.

Answer (score 1):

It's mandatory to have tns_admin with the oracle wallet path for unmanaged driver where as it is not required for managed driver.